# G++ object model

Tags: c++, object-model

Today i read the <>.i encountered a problem.as the book says,

```
class Concrete1 {
public:
int val;
char bit1;
};

class Concrete2 : public Concrete1 {
public:
char bit2;
};

class Concrete3 : public Concrete2 {
public:
char bit3;
};
```

when i run the code in mingw g++, the space of the three classes are 8, 12, 12.But when i run the code in vs2012, the space of the three classes are 8, 12, 16. of cource, the code in vs2012 is with no problem.But for the space in g++, i have some questions,and i try to write a sample code to see whether a problem. the sample code as follows :

```
int main(void)
{
    Concrete2 con2;
    memset(&con2, 0, sizeof(con2));
    Concrete3  con3;
    con3.val = 3;
    con3.bit2 =  4;
    con3.bit3 = 5;
    Concrete2* con_ptr2 = &con2;
    Concrete2* con_ptr3 = &con3;
    *con_ptr3 = *con_ptr2;
    cout << con3.bit3<< endl;
    cout << sizeof(Concrete1) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(Concrete2) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(Concrete3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and for the object model in g++, the code is with no problem.why after the code "*con_ptr3 = *con_ptr2;", the con3.bit3 is 5 not 0?
can anyone help me ?

Comment: Set a breakpoint, step through it step by step.

Comment: i hava set a breakpoint, and i have seen the result.but i don't know how to explain the result!

Comment: What is the value of every pointer and variable in every line?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the result is correct, bit3 should be 5 because that assignment only affects the Concrete1 and Concrete2 portions of con3.

Assignment is member-wise, not byte-wise.
So "*com_ptr3 = *con_ptr2" is not the same as "memcpy(con_ptr3, con_ptr2, sizeof(Concrete2))"
The default copy constructor and default assignment operators must copy the data in memberwise and in the order that the members are defined in the class.
This also means that you cannot count on the padding bytes having any particular value.

The size differences is just because VS and gcc handle padding slightly differently.
gcc apparently is able to pack bit2 and bit3 into the same 32-bit word, while VS doesn't.
Strange that gcc can't also pack bit1 in as well, leading to sizes 8,8,8.

This might be because gcc considers Concrete1 to be POD, but Concrete 2 and 3 are not. The standard has stricter requirements for how data is laid out in POD types compared to non-pod. The compiler has more flexibity in class data layout for non-pod types.